# Как подписать apk , что бы при установке из файла андройд не ругался на "Подозрительное приложение"?

Tags: android, android-sdk, apk, openjdk

Всё происходит в консоли на линуксе, без студии.
Как создавать ключ и подписывать информации много, соответственно вот такие шаги я предпринял:
Генерю ключ:

```
/opt/java/openjdk/bin/keytool -genkeypair -alias test_al -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -keystore my_key.jks
```

Собираю apk, выравниваю, в финале подписываю только созданным ключом:

```
opt/android-sdk/build-tools/33.0.2/apksigner sign --ks ./my_key.jks --ks-key-alias test_al --ks-pass pass:'FNWT4g19TP' --key-pass pass:'FNWT4g19TP' ./may_app.apk
```

Никаких ошибок

И когда начинаю устанавливать приложение из этого файла may_app.apk,
На телефоне получаю сообщение
"Подозрительное приложение..."(приложу скрин)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как так подписать приложение что бы андройд не запугивал пользователей?

Получается недостаточно сделать такой ключ, надо еще приложение в маркет загрузить или типо того?

Или в командах выше ошибка?

(В исследовательских целях пошёл скачивать пиратские apk(осуждаю) в стиле всё фильмы онлайн и тд, и все ставятся без всяких предупреждений, информация о подписи имеется, нейтрально во всех полях android, как они это делают?)

Comment: никак. это нормальное поведение, если приложение устанавливается из АПК, а не качается из ПлейМаркета.

Comment: @Wlad Вообще честно говоря у меня есть другой сертификат, этого же приложения с которым оно выкладывалось и если подпишу им через opt/android-sdk/build-tools/33.0.2/apksigner, то предупреждения не будет если ставить apk и что насчет пиратских apk'шек, там тоже нет предупреждения.

Comment: Ваш сертификат должен быть подписан доверенным промежуточным центром сертификации, только тогда он не будет ругаться на него. Берите сертификат от приложения, которое есть в маркете, и подписывайте им.